# How can I write this code in MySQL in a shorter and better way?

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 3 tables in the database and they have no relation. How can I write this code in a short form? Sorry for my bad english already.

MySQL Code;

```
SELECT
    *,
    (SELECT COUNT(c2.id) FROM comments AS c2 WHERE c2.phone_number = comments.phone_number AND c2.country_code = comments.country_code AND c2.approve = "0" AND c2.deleted_at IS NULL) AS comment_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(f.id) FROM flag_numbers AS f WHERE f.phone_number = comments.phone_number AND f.country_code = comments.country_code AND comments.approve = "0" AND comments.deleted_at IS NULL) AS flag_count 
FROM comments 
WHERE approve = "0" AND deleted_at IS NULL 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: evidently seems they have relations in terms of some columns.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is pretty good, but the following is a bit simpler:

```
SELECT c.*,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.phone_Number, c.country_code) as comment_count,
       (SELECT COUNT(f.id)
        FROM flag_numbers f
        WHERE f.phone_number = c.phone_number AND
              f.country_code = c.country_code 
      ) AS flag_count 
FROM comments c
WHERE c.approve = '0' AND c.deleted_at IS NULL 
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

If `approve` is a number, then remove the single quotes.  Don't quote number constants.

The differences:

- Replacement of the first subquery with a window function for `comment_count`.
- Removal of the redundant comment filters in the `flag_count`.